# How can I determine the debugged program/process in handlers of EnvDTE.Events.DebuggerEvents?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions

I am creating a Visual Studio Extension that performs some tasks when debugging of a specific application is stopped. This is my code for handling the debugger event:

```
    ...
    DTE2 ide = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE2;
    if (ide != null)
    {
        debuggerEvents = ide.Events.DebuggerEvents;
        debuggerEvents.OnEnterDesignMode += DebuggerEvents_OnEnterDesignMode;
    }
}

private static void DebuggerEvents_OnEnterDesignMode(dbgEventReason Reason)
{
    ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();

    DTE2 ide = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE2;
    if (ide != null && ide.Debugger.CurrentProcess != null)
    {
        DebuggedProcName = ide.Debugger.CurrentProcess.Name;
    }

    if (Reason == dbgEventReason.dbgEventReasonStopDebugging &&
        DebuggedProcName == "MyApp")
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem is that ide.Debugger.CurrentProcess and .CurrentProgram is null in OnEnterDesignMode(). They are not null in OnEnterBreakMode() but that one might not be called. How can I determine the currently debugged program/process in a Visual Studio extension?

Comment: Did you enter the event `OnEnterDesignMode` and then face the issue that `ide.Debugger.CurrentProcess` is null?  Or try to use `DTE2 ide = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE2;`

Comment: Yes, that is what happened. The same  in OnEnterRunMode (). The only handler that can provides the program/process is OnEnterBreakMode(). The second suggestion did not improve the situation.

Comment: According to [the below official link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.debuggereventsclass.onenterdesignmode?view=visualstudiosdk-2017), the `OnEnterDesignMode event` means leaving run/debug mode, that’s why cannot get the current debugging process. Fired when leaving run mode or debug mode, and when the debugger establishes design mode after debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to perform a specific task if debugging of a certain project is stopped. Since using the event handler seems impossible I helped myself with a menu command that is executed when I press Ctrl + F5. After performing the task this command also kills the debugged process which effectively stops debugging. Rather rude, I guess, but I can live with this solution.